# Java reading from text file to array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program that reads numbers from a text file to calculate the average. I am trying to make it read and display them with the code (found below under error) however I am getting a blank screen and this error at runtime:

### Stack trace

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
    at list.main(list.java:53)
    at __SHELL19.run(__SHELL19.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at list.main(list.java:53)
    at __SHELL20.run(__SHELL20.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: FirstPa.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at list.main(list.java:47)
    at __SHELL21.run(__SHELL21.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:774)
```

### Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class reading 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     try 
     {
        List<Integer> column = new ArrayList<Integer>();   

        Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new FileReader("FirstPart.txt")); 

        while (myfile.hasNext()) 
        {     
            column.add(myfile.nextInt());      
        }
        myfile.close();
        System.out.println("column elements are:\n" + column); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: `myfile.nextInt()` do you only have numbers in this txt file?

Comment: Is your folder where FirstPart.txt is in your path? Try using absolute path to the file.

Comment: the code and the text file are in the same folder

Comment: Put the text file in the root of your project folder not your src folder (should not be in package with code)...

Comment: The exception stack trace also shows java.io.FileNotFoundException: FirstPa.txt Did you give correct file path?

Comment: I am using BlueJ it doesn't create src folder etc

Comment: Another thing I noticed. In the code, you have `FirstPart.txt`, but the error says `FirstPa.txt`. They don't match (missing the 'rt'). Look into making sure the file name is correct as well.

Comment: Figure out where your program is looking for the root...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the path instead of just `FirstPart.txt` like `src/main/java/FirstPart.txt`

according to the error the file is not found.

Comment: if it is in Desktop/NewFolder etc do you specify those as well?

Comment: you should always provide absolute path to the file. If its in Desktop/New Folder, then pass it as "C:\xyz\Desktop\New folder"

Answer (score -3):

maybe u can check first if your scanner hasnext int like in this example:

```
public class ScannerDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";

      // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

      // find the next int token and print it
      // loop for the whole scanner
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {

         // if the next is a int, print found and the int
         if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextInt());
         }
         // if no int is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
         System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());
      }

      // close the scanner
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: this gave this output :

Not Found :Hello
Not Found :World!
Found :3
Not Found :+
Not Found :3.0
Not Found :=
Not Found :6.0
Not Found :true

Comment: You didn't put in an `else` statement, so both items will print, hence the confusing output.

Comment: you shouldnt copy paste the code. i gave you an example what you should understand what it do and fit the "idea" into your project. try to learn why your programm dont work and dont just search for code you can paste into your project.

Comment: @Izu - Your statement doesn't apply if the code to be copied (a.k.a. your's) also doesn't work.